# Man md5 displays dgst man page

Tags: terminal, macos, open-source

I just wanted to look at the man page for the command md5. So I typed `man md5` but it displayed the man page of `dgst` instead of [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/md5.1.html).

Any idea why and how I could access this manpage from the terminal ?

Edit : `man -w` return the path used to look for manpages :  `/opt/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/texbin/man`

But where does this come from ? Not from my `/private/etc/man.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer myself to my question after a bit a research :

To see how the manpath is build, looking at `manpath -d` is quite interesting.

`man` uses `MANPATH`/`MANPATH_MAP` (as defined in `/private/etc/man.conf) and`$PATH` from the environment variables to build it's search path.

Because of MacPort my `$PATH` starts with the multiple subdirectories in `/opt/local/`. 
Therefore my manpath will start with `/opt/local/` manpages.

Comment: Interesting. I had seen `MANPATH_MAP` referenced, but didn't bring it up because it wasn't clear to me from `man`'s own manpage how it worked. This is enlightening, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

On my ML installation, `man md5` does indeed show the `MD5(1)` man page.

It's possible some local software installation or configuration is causing the display of a man page for `dgst` instead, though (which [appears to be part of OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dgst.html).)

A few things to check:

Do you have the `MANPATH` environment variable set in your shell?  It could be looking in an alternative directory for manpages before hitting the system manpages.  `MANPATH` does not appear to be set by default.

Are there alternative `MANPATH` directives in `/private/etc/man.conf`?  My system has

```
MANPATH /usr/share/man
MANPATH /usr/local/share/man
MANPATH /usr/X11/man
```

Has `/usr/share/man/man1/md5.1` been replaced by a symlink to another man page that could be producing the `dgst` content?  Try

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/man/man1/md5.1
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  12332 Nov 16  2012 /usr/share/man/man1/man.1
```

If `/usr/share/man/man1/md5.1` has not been changed, then you can read its content specifically this way:

```
$ man /usr/share/man/man1/md5.1
```

Comment: I have no MANPATH in my environment variables, MANPATH are the same than yours and  `man /usr/share/man/man1/md5.1` shows the right man page. I still don't get why I dgst's manpage.